# Catch exception thrown in a listener

Tags: dart, stream, listener, unhandled-exception

This is my first post on StackOverflow ! I hope it will be useful for many devs !
Here's the Issue :

I'm using a listener to check a bluetooth device state.
In that listener, if I get a disconnected event after a connected event (the user refused the pairing) => I throw RefusedAssociationException();

```
bool wasCo = false; 
bluetoothDevice.state.listen((event) async {
    
    if (event == BluetoothDeviceState.connected ||
          event == BluetoothDeviceState.connecting) wasCo = true;

    if (wasCo && event == BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected) {
      print("We throw RefusedAssociationException");
      wasCo = false;
      throw RefusedAssociationException();
    }
}).onError((handleError) => print("HANDLE ERROR IS : $handleError"));

await bluetoothDevice.connect();
```

This code doesn't allow me to handle the RefusedAssociationException().
Here is the error I get :

```
I/flutter (18595): We throw RefusedAssociationException
E/flutter (18595): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'RefusedAssociationException'
E/flutter (18595): #0      BleLocalDataSourceImpl.connectToDevice.<anonymous closure> (package:tikee_remote_v2/features/tikee/data/datasources/local/ble_local_data_source.dart:107:9)
E/flutter (18595): #1      BleLocalDataSourceImpl.connectToDevice.<anonymous closure> (package:tikee_remote_v2/features/tikee/data/datasources/local/ble_local_data_source.dart:97:34)
E/flutter (18595): #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
E/flutter (18595): #3      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (18595): #4      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter (18595): #5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter (18595): #6      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
E/flutter (18595): #7      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
E/flutter (18595): #8      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
E/flutter (18595): #9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1420:47)
E/flutter (18595): #10     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (18595): #11     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter (18595): #12     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter (18595): #13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
E/flutter (18595): #14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (18595): #15     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter (18595): #16     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter (18595): #17     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (18595): #18     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

Does anyone knows how to catch exceptions thrown in a listener ?
What is the best practice here ?

Thank you very much

Comment: "Best practice" really depends on your ideology which, like god, depends on people. Some people don't even believe... in error handling that is :D . More seriously, I would use the `Either` type from any functional programming language to force error handling. Here is an article about this: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/better-error-handling-with-either-type-in-dart-b91bef20d716

Comment: Hello @Lulupointu, first of all thanks for your time.
I've considered using the either type (which is very powerful btw), but in my case I don't want to kill the thread and keep listening after an error is thrown !

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure from your comment. You DO want to continue to listen ?

Answer (score 1):

The `stream.listen` callbacks are independent. If you get a data event, the `onData` callback is called, if you get an error from the stream, the `onError` event is called. (Your `onData` callback is also marked `async` for no obvious reason, check whether that's necessary.)

If you throw in either callback, it becomes an uncaught asynchronous error and is reported to the current `Zone`'s uncaught error handler.

An error in the `onData` callback is not forwarded to the `onError` handler, which it seems you are assuming.

It's not entirely clear which behavior you *do* want. Where is the error you throw supposed to surface? Is it supposed to end the `listen`? (If so, remember the subscription and cancel it, unless you know the stream will close by itself after that event).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very interesting content.